# FOSRESTBundle format_listener changing host is not working

Tags: symfony, yaml, fosrestbundle

so i have the following configuration on the fos_rest.yml

## FOS Rest Bundle

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: force
    body_converter:
        enabled: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: force
        formats:
            json: true
        templating_formats:
            html: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api', priorities: [ json ], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: true }
            - { path: '^/',host: 'api.office.dev', priorities: [ json ], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: true }
            - { path: '^/', priorities: [ html, '*/*' ], fallback_format: ~, prefer_extension: true }
    exception:
        codes:
            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': 404
            'Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException': HTTP_CONFLICT
        messages:
            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': true
    allowed_methods_listener: true
    access_denied_listener:
        json: true
    body_listener: true
    disable_csrf_role: ROLE_USER
```

its working on my local machine so i have `api.office.dev` in hosts file which redirect to localhost

when i wanted to test the api from android emulator i needed to change the host to my local ip `192.168.178.63` after but its not changed and i am getting 404 on the routes now.
I tried the following :
clearing the cache.
removing var files.
dumping and installing assets.
with no luck and when i run `bin/api_console debug:route` i am still getting the host `api.office.dev` which i removed from everywhere in the project with no luck its like its stuck somewhere. please notice that i have more than one application and more than one console.
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

found the problem i was setting the host in the `routing.yml`